# How do I assign an NSManagedObject that I get from fetched result controller to the entity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have a model class I created from the .model file by going to the editor > create NSManagedObject subclass for my entity named Target.

I want to fetch the first Target object I have in my Table view controller and get to some specific attribute of that entity.

For now I know how to get the managed object :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
NSManagedObject *record = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
```

But now I want to have the entity object that I can get its attribute values from...like target.body

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Target : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * body;
```

This is the entity class..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already returning the correct object type.

You just need to give the compiler a hint that your call to

```
[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

is actually going to return an instance of `Target`.

---

You just need to declare the correct variable type

```
Target *record = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Obviously to get this to compile you'll need to bring the header in at the top of the file that wants to use `Target`

```
#import "Target.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

record is a NSManagedObject.  If you performed a fetch on Target, the record should not just be an NSManagedObject, it should also be a Target which inherits from NSManagedObject.  So instead of `NSManagedObject *record =` do `Target *record =`.  Make sure you call `#import "Target.h"` and you should be able to call `record.body`.